# Traverse Javascript array and append rows to html table with jQuery --

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table, dynamic-tables

I am struggling with some jQuery array traversing at the moment.
I have some data like this --

[image]

What I want - is to traverse this array, and add the values to an html table.

Like --

```
Product      Unit Price          Quantity             Total
-----------------------------
------------------------------------
--------------------------
--------------------------
```

The code I wrote is --

```
    parseRowData() {
    var htmlApp = "";
    $.each(this.dTable, function (ind, val) {
        //var varArr = new Array();
        //varArr.push(val);
        htmlApp += "<tr><td>" + val[ind]["product"] + "</td><td>" + val[ind]["unitprice"] + "</td><td>" + val[ind]["quantity"] + "</td><td>" + val[ind]["total"] + "</td></tr>";
        $("invTable tbody").appendTo(htmlApp);
    });

}
```

Initially I tried using simple for loops also, but I am not getting proper results. Either a blank table or a table with same data rows being repeated several times.
Please help me a little bit in structuring the loop logic.

Comment: If the contents of this.dTable are exactly what you posted in the image, then you should use val["unitprice"] directly, without adding the index. $.each will read each element of the array separately.

Comment: Hi @VictoriaRuiz I tried it. using 'val["product"], val["quantity"] ...' etc. Nope. Also tried(just as experiment) 'this.dTable[ind]["total"]...... '  also. Not that one either.....
maybe the simple for loops for this case? Just thinking..

Comment: I'm not sure what is in your dTable... Could you create a [mcve]? Also, try console.log of val - that should tell you a lot.

Comment: yes sure, @VictoriaRuiz if I do simple console.log(val) I get this -- https://pasteboard.co/HrgUGv8.png

Comment: It's an object. Try val.product instead of val["product"]

Comment: yes, I checked that; it works, @VictoriaRuiz
now what I am trying is -- create <tr> <td> ..........  </tr> to make rows for each of these objects and add to an html table to complete the display of data in my table; that I am finding tough;

Comment: Here is the fiddle, @VictoriaRuiz I have tried to replicate the scenario --

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lheb5p0/9/
Kindly look once,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a proper answer is in order.

Knowing that `console.log(val)` returns the right content (see https://pasteboard.co/HrgUGv8.png), we also know that `val` is an object.

You can then call each of the properties of that object by doing `val.product`, `val.unitprice`, etc.

You are concatenating the newly created rows in the `htmlApp` variable.

Once you're done with your $.each loop, you need to insert them into `$("invTable tbody")`. So:

$.each(this.dTable, function (ind, val) {
    //all your  building goes here
}); 
$("invTable tbody").html(htmlApp);

Doing this, you replace the entire contents of `<tbody>` with all the rows you concatenated within `htmlApp`.

Some more info: 
If you wanted to add the rows individually to your table, you could do it from within the loop, but you wouldn't concatenate them in htmlApp.

You would do this:

```
 $.each(this.dTable, function (ind, val) {

        htmlApp = "<tr><td>" + val.product + "</td>... so on and so forth</tr>";
        $("invTable tbody").append(htmlApp);
    });
```

Note that I used `append` instead of `appendTo`.

And finally... `invTable` is not an HTML element, so I'm guessing it is either a class or an ID. If it's a class, you need to indicate that in your selector: `$(".invTable tbody")`. If it's an ID, you use `$("#invTable tbody")`

Comment: I did this --
        parseRowData() {
        var htmlApp = "";
        $.each(this.dTable, function (ind, val) {
            htmlApp += "<tr><td>" + val.product + "</td><td>" + val.unitprice + "</td><td>" + val.total + "</td><td>" + val.quantity + "</td></tr>"
            $("invTable tbody").html(htmlApp);
        });
        
    }

No luck. As alternate, I also tried append and appendTo, but no; Is my tr building logic correct as per this scenario? @VictoriaRuiz

Comment: yes @VictoriaRuiz exactly as I did. strange, it shows nothing!     :  ((

Comment: I don't think that's what you did. But it's time for you to add that [mcve] to your question. Use the JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet function and add the last version of your code, so that we can play with it.

Comment: okk,.... I see,
same data beiing repeated multiple times @VictoriaRuiz, see this one -- https://pasteboard.co/Hrh5i92.png

Comment: You're still concatenating. Don't use +=, use = if you append from within the loop.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/Hrhh9Rv.png
Yes. Without you would have been tough for me. @VictoriaRuiz; thanks for the guidance; display is fine now;

Comment: Cool :-) Don't forget to mark this as a right answer